# Calculating Think time, pacing time and Transactions per second

Tags: jmeter

I want to know how to calculate Think time, pacing time and Transactions per second.

Requirement is :

No of users : 500
Need to do 1hr execution
Need to specify Think time and pacing.

My script "Medevolve" contains 7 transactions  and average response time is 18seconds.

[image]

Kindly clarify my doubt.

Thanks
KVS Kumar

Answer (score 0):

Hi the general method I use is the following one.
Start with one user and see how much time it takes to run the job without any pause. 
This will give you the maximum throughput per single thread.

Then set a throughput timer at thread level. 
This will insert pauses, making the thread throughput more independent from response time.
Also, this will allow you  to compare the thread execution time with actual user execution time. 
I usually seek a simple ratio. 
 1:1 is the best, if possible. 
Then start adding threads and the throughput should grow linearly with threads.

HTH